# AccessViolationException at no specific code-location while debugging

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, debugging, access-violation

I get an `AccessViolationException` while debugging an application, but don't get this exception while running this application as release without attached debugger. The application is a very thread-intensive (up to 10000+) network-server (tcp/socket).

The application has run the whole last night compiled as release, without attached debugger and under heavy load. In fact the application didn't ever crash without attached debugger.

When I run the application compiled as `Release` with attached debugger I get an `AccessViolationException`-Exception (sometimes). This exception just gets thrown without any hint where this exception occurs. When I press Ok in the appearing exception-box in Visual Studio and then navigate to the thread where the exception occurred. I can't see any code or stacktrace there:

[image: Thread with exception has no memory-location.]
*(Thread #186840 has no memory-location.)*

This is my (reduced) test-program: [example-code](http://kwick.ghost-home.de/dist/q2.zip). (You should have enough ram and cpu and you should compile it as release. First start the server-application, then generate load with the client-application.)

Now my question(s): **How can I debug such errors? Does anyone know about a bug in .NET while debugging such thread-intensive programs?**

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. The project is a `Any Cpu`; `.NET 4.0` `C#` project. I have installed all windows update patches and was running this on Windows 8.1. The JIT compiler compiled the code to x64.

Comment: *"thread-intensive (up to 10000+)"*, unless you have 10000+ cores on your computer, you may want to rethink your design. Your CPU is probably spending more time context switching than working.

Comment: Thats not the point. The threads are mostly waiting for blocking socket calls.

Comment: `running this application as release without attached debugger` - is this possible?

Comment: Does each thread have its own socket?

Comment: @jmc Every application compiled as release and then launched with double-clicking it in explorer is launched without attached debugger.

Comment: @Matthias but not run inside Visual Studio right?

Comment: Does your application have a User Interface? What is the `ApartmentState` of the threads? Please post the part of the code where the threads are created, I'm not sure if a lot of people will take the time to download your test program.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(worker); is used to start threads and it has no user interface. It is a console application and will later be changed to a service.

Comment: When using secondary threads, exception are not thrown to main thread. The solution for that (not directly solving your problem) is to encapsulate the code of the tread start in a try catch. In the catch, get the exception message and stack trace and forward them to the main thread (e.g. setting a global  exception string set to empty before calling all parallel process). In the main thread, test if an exception occurs on some thread, and display or log it.

Comment: @jmc You can run an application in visual studio without debugging and compiled as release by switching to release and the select start without debugging.

Comment: @Graffito But while the application is running in the debugger, the debugger should stop and show the code location highlighted. This works at least when I manually throw an exception in a thread.

Comment: just an idea: do you use an unmanaged resources?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I had unmanaged resources and unsafe-code but i did remove everything and the "just .net dependend" program (see download) does also have this issue.

Comment: The type of exceptions shown in debug mode depend on the the debug exceptions setting : "Thrown" and/or "User-handled". In my VS2008 environment and with the defaults (Thrown unchecked), I don't catch in debug mode the thread exceptions. Perhaps, the process for manually thrown exceptions is different than systemm exceptions such as nullReference.

Comment: @Graffito But it catches the exception. VS just can't tell me where it comes from, nor can it show me the stack-trace of the thread in question.

Comment: So if you want to get the trace and message, you may try what I suggested : encapsulate the thread process in a try catch and use Console.WriteLine to report exception message and StackTrace in case of exception.

Comment: @Graffito I doubt that this will help, but I will give it a try. (All calls and operations in question are already surrounded by try/catch.)

Comment: @Graffito Now I have surrounded every `ThreadPool`-call and any method-content with try/catch (+Console.WriteLine) and the exception keeps getting thrown. I think this is no problem with my code.

Comment: Check if it was raised from finalization thread. If so, some dispose methods and finalizers were wrongly implemented.

Comment: @LexLi How can I do this? I don't have any `Dispose`-methods in the example-code.